# SQL sub query date issue

Tags: sql, ms-access

The issue I am having is massively basic all I'm trying to do it use the following SQL code

```
SELECT *
FROM [Car For Sale]
WHERE CFS_Selling_Price IN (SELECT MAX (CFS_Selling_Price)
                            FROM [Car For Sale] 
                            HAVING CFS_Status ='Sold');
```

which works already along with the following SQL code

```
CFS_Sold_Date > dateadd("m",-1,date())
```

in order to reduce the results from the most expensive car sold to the most expensive car sold this month. I've tried figuring it out for myself to no avail anyone able to help ?

Comment: Which SQL product are you using?

Comment: Ok, I've added the appropriate tag for you - make sure you do that next time, you'll get the right people to see your question :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't know thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding the new expression to the HAVING clause with an AND?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Car For Sale]
WHERE CFS_Selling_Price IN 
   (SELECT MAX (CFS_Selling_Price)
    FROM [Car For Sale] 
    WHERE CFS_Status ='Sold'
    AND CFS_Sold_Date > dateadd("m",-1,date()));
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple the whole time I was trying to add the and into the wrong place. Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: I'm surprised that either this or the original query works.  The conditions should really be in a `where` clause, not a `having` clause.

Comment: Access will accept Having, as far as I know, but Where is better.